# Problem with invalidation of STL iterators when calling erase

Tags: c++, iterator, deque, erase, invalidation

The STL standard defines that when an erase occurs on containers such as std::deque, std::list etc iterators are invalidated.

My question is as follows, assuming the list of integers contained in a std::deque, and a pair of indicies indicating a range of elements in the std::deque, what is the correct way to delete all even elements?

So far I have the following, however the problem here is that the assumed end is invalidated after an erase:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
   std::deque<int> deq;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; deq.push_back(i++));

   // range, 11th to 51st element
   std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t> r(10,50);

   std::deque<int>::iterator it = deq.begin() + r.first;
   std::deque<int>::iterator end = deq.begin() + r.second;

   while (it != end)
   {
      if (*it % 2 == 0)
      {
         it = deq.erase(it);
      }
      else
        ++it;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Examining how std::remove_if is implemented, it seems there is a very costly copy/shift down process going on.

- Is there a more efficient way of achieving the above without all the copy/shifts
- In general is deleting/erasing an element more expensive than swapping it with the next nth value in the sequence (where n is the number of elements deleted/removed so far)

**Note:** Answers should assume the sequence size is quite large, +1mil elements and that on average 1/3 of elements would be up for erasure.

Comment: I believe that an `deque::erase` invalidates all iterators.

Comment: Erasure doesn't affect iterators/pointers to non-erased elements in a std::list. Please refer to this list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules/6438087
for full invalidation rules.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the [Erase-Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom). I think the Wikipedia article linked even shows what you're doing -- removing odd elements.

The copying that `remove_if` does is no more costly than what happens when you delete elements from the middle of the container. It might even be more efficient.

Comment: @Oxsnarder: But you probably have even more copies going on using individual `erase` calls, as [Karl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342324/problem-with-invalidation-of-stl-iterators-when-calling-erase/4342729#4342729) points out. The fact of the matter is, deleting elements from the middle of a `vector` or `deque` is inherently inefficient. If you need to do it a lot, you may be better off using a `list`. In that case, either use the member function `remove_if` or the kind of erase loop you've specified. The `end` will not be invalidated for a `list`.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `.erase()` also results in "a very costly copy/shift down process going on.". When you erase an element from the middle of the container, every other element after that point must be shifted down one spot into the available space. If you erase multiple elements, you incur that cost for every erased element. Some of the non-erased elements will move several spots, but are forced to move one spot at a time instead of all at once. That is very inefficient.

The standard library algorithms `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` optimize this work. They use a clever trick to ensure that every moved element is only moved once. This is much, much **faster** than what you are doing yourself, contrary to your intuition.

The pseudocode is like this:

```
read_location <- beginning of range.
write_location <- beginning of range.
while read_location != end of range:
    if the element at read_location should be kept in the container:
        copy the element at the read_location to the write_location.
        increment the write_location.
    increment the read_location.
```

As you can see, every element in the original sequence is considered exactly once, and if it needs to be kept, it gets copied exactly once, to the current write_location. It will never be looked at again, because the write_location can never run in front of the read_location.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that deque is a contiguous memory container (like vector, and probably sharing implementation), so removing elements mid-container necessarily means copying subsequent elements over the hole.  You just want to make sure you're doing one iteration and copying each not-to-be-deleted object directly to its final position, rather than moving all objects one by one during each delete.  `remove_if` is efficient and appropriate in this regard, your `erase` loop is not: it does massive amounts of unnecessary copying.

FWIW - alternatives:

- add a "deleted" state to your objects and mark them deleted in place, but then every time you operate on the container you'll need to check yourself
- use a list, which is implemented using pointers to previous and next elements, such that removing a list element alters the adjacent points to bypass that element: no copying, efficient iteration, just no random access, more small (i.e. inefficient) heap allocations and pointer overheads

What to choose depends on the nature, relative frequency, and performance requirements of specific operations (e.g. it may be that you can afford slow removals if they're done at non-critical times, but need fastest-possible iteration - whatever it is, make sure you understand your needs and the implications of the various data structures).

Comment: how does one add a deleted state to a deque<int> of 10mil elements in an efficient and sensisble manner?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative that hasn't been mentioned is to create a new `deque`, copy the elements that you want to keep into it, and `swap` it with the old `deque`.

```
void filter(std::deque<int>& in, std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t> range) {
    std::deque<int> out;
    std::deque<int>::const_iterator first = in.begin();
    std::deque<int>::const_iterator curr = first + range.first;
    std::deque<int>::const_iterator last = first + range.second;
    out.reserve(in.size() - (range.second-range.first));
    std::copy(first, curr, std::back_inserter(out));
    while (curr != last) {
        if (*curr & 1) {
            out.push_back(*curr);
        }
        ++curr;
    }
    std::copy(last, in.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
    in.swap(out);
}
```

I'm not sure if you have enough memory to create a copy, but it usually is faster and easier to make a copy instead of trying to inline erase elements from a large collection.  If you still see memory thrashing, then figure out how many elements you are going to keep by calling `std::count_if` and reserve that many.  This way you would have a single memory allocation.